# Apply CSS rule to a group of elements between two other elements

Tags: javascript, css

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <blockquote>...</blockquote>
  <p>...</p>
  <div class="bbb">...</div>
  <div class="ccc">...</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to apply `display: none` to everything between `aaa` and `bbb`? That is, to `<blockquote>` and `<p>`. (The contents is not limited to `blockquote` and `p`. For example, it could be `<div>` or `<pre>`.)

Comment: How do you define "between"? `bbb` is *inside* `aaa`, so there's nothing *between* them... Or would you like to check them in the order of open-tags?

Comment: "Between" is not a good word, but it is too hard to describe it properly. (The title should be short.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript (for example to apply this change programmatically), you can get all the children of the element with class `aaa` and then iterate over them applying the style, stopping when you reach the one with class `bbb`.

```
let parent = document.querySelector('.aaa');

for (let child of parent.children) {
    if (child.classList.contains('bbb'))
        break;

    child.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You will need two rules:

```css
.aaa > * {
  display:none;
}
.aaa > .bbb,
.aaa > .bbb ~ * {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <blockquote>block</blockquote>
  <p>ppp</p>
  <div class="bbb">bbb</div>
  <div class="ccc">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer and it will be definitely useful for me and for other users. But since JS is my primary way currently, I accepted the answer by Marco Bonelli.

Comment: @johnc.j. You should *never* use JavaScript for something you can also achieve with CSS.

Answer (score -3):

```css
#xxx{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa">
  <div id='xxx'>
  <blockquote>.zzz..</blockquote>
  <p>.yyy..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bbb">...</div>
  <div class="ccc">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While technically correct, there are solutions that are better suited using just css, such as the one by Temani Afif

Comment: better suited? how?